# Infinite dimensional smooth projective geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, projective-geometry, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, banach-manifold, hilbert-manifolds

Are there two infinite dimensional (Banach or Hilbert) manifolds  $(P,L)$ which satisfy the axioms of a smooth projective geometry desribed in this page: [Smooth Projectove Geometry](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_projective_plane)

Comment: If X and Y are two non-isomorphic Banach spaces would their projectivizations P(X) and P(Y) be examples of what you ask for? I'm not sure, just a thought.